# Error when trying to connect PHP7 Laravel to MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, ubuntu, forge

We have been stuck on the problem of trying to connect our Laravel Forge HHVM PHP7 API to our frontend MongoDB, hosted on MLab.  We are using all the latest drivers, correct naming conventions, (EG: mongodb and not mongo).

The system is deployed using Forge, onto an Ubuntu 16.04 DigitalOcean droplet.  It has been three weeks of trying different solutions and we are still no closer.  The error that we get is:

```
Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found.
```

However, we are referencing it correctly and and all drivers have complied and are working when testing.  If I run the following, all is working:

```
$ php -i | grep 'Mongo'
MongoDB Support => enabled
```

If anyone can help, I am at my whits end as to how to fix this.

Comment: Did you install a Mongo PHP extension?

Comment: Yes!  But we have just managed to get it working.  Made some changes this morning and needed to do a hard restart to effect changes.